# Qual a diferença entre ISNULL e COALESCE numa pesquisa?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

Estou com dúvida na utilização do `ISNULL` e `COALESCE`.

Atualmente ao criar uma *query* no SQL Server, fiquei com dúvida sobre `ISNULL` e `COALESCE`,
realizei algumas pesquisas e consegui descobrir a diferença de ambos. Só que me surgiu algumas 
duvidas que não consegui encontrar.

Realizei a seguinte *query*:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dúvidas:
    Ao ler em alguns sites vi que o `ISNULL` OU `COALESCE` tem alguma diferença na hora do `select` em banco
    só que não consegui descobrir qual deles, pois os dois tem o mesmo comportamento ao realizar a seguinte *query*?

```
SELECT  'A' + ISNULL(NULLIF('abc', 'abc'), ' ') + 'A' AS Using_ISNULL,
Resultado: A A

SELECT  'A' + COALESCE(NULLIF('abc', 'abc'), ' ') + 'A' AS Using_ISNULL
Resultado: A A
```

Só que em alguns sites diziam `ISNULL` ou `COALESCE` quando string ficaria da seguinte forma
Ex: Se a Coluna tiver o Tamanho `VARCHAR(50)`

```
SELECT  'A' + COALESCE OU ISNULL(NULLIF('abc', 'abc'), ' ') + 'A' AS Using_ISNULL
Resultado: A(ESPAÇO 48 "")A
```

foi isso que pude entender, mais nenhum site mostrava exemplos para melhor entendimento, queria saber 
qual a diferença de ambos na questão em banco?

Ficou um pouco difícil descrever minha dúvida.

Comment: Não sei se você viu, mas ontem complementei minha resposta, e agora há pouco dei outra melhorada nela. Inicialmente eu não tinha reparado na discrepância dos resultados que você mostrou, mas agora acredito que a resposta esclareça sua dúvida.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

A principal diferença de funcionalidade é que o [`COALESCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) aceita *n* argumentos, retornando o primeiro com valor não `NULL` entre eles. O [`ISNULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) só aceita dois argumentos, um possivelmente `NULL`, e outro para retornar se o primeiro for `NULL`.

Por exemplo, isto só dá para fazer com `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(col1, col2, col3, col4) AS valor;
```

Isso seleciona o primeiro valor que não seja nulo entre as quatro colunas passadas. Acredito que essa diferença você já conheça. No seu exemplo você só passa um argumento, então sob esse aspecto não há diferença entre usar uma função ou a outra. Mas é sempre bom lembrar que `COALESCE` faz parte do padrão da linguagem SQL, enquanto o `ISNULL` não faz.

Outra diferença (que é a que importa para a sua pergunta): o `ISNULL` retorna o tipo do seu primeiro argumento, enquanto o `COALESCE` retorna o tipo de maior precedência entre os passados. Os resultados estranhos que você mostra no screenshot são uma combinação disso com o efeito do [`NULLIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx), que, segundo a documentação (grifo meu):

> NULLIF returns the first expression if the two expressions are not equal. If the expressions are equal, NULLIF returns a null value **of the type of the first expression**.

Ou seja, o `NULL` que ele retorna é tipado (nunca imaginei isso) com base no tipo do primeiro argumento. Em todos os exemplos, seria um `CHAR(3)`, `VARCHAR(3)` ou algo do tipo. Isso força o *cast* do segundo argumento do `ISNULL` para o mesmo tipo. No caso do valor número, o tipo é incompatível e o resultado é `*`.

Comment: Boa tarde bfavaretto. Obrigado pela resposta, Foi bem o que eu queria saber. Tipado eis o motivo

Comment: Pois é, é bem estranho. Estou acostumado com linguagens onde `NULL` é a única instância de um tipo próprio, não sabia que em SQL havia múltiplos tipos de `NULL`. Mas faz sentido ser assim, pensando na maneira como as funções da linguagem operam.

Comment: Tem uma diferença de performance entre as funções quando você passa uma subquery para verificação ex: ```select coalesce((select max(id) from produtos), 0)```, neste caso o ```ISNULL``` tem um ótimo ganho de performance.

Comment: @TiagoOliveiradeFreitas Fui pesquisar mais e achei [este artigo](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull), talvez te interesse.

Comment: Acabei de ver uma referência que trata de outra diferença do `COALESCE` em relação ao `ISNULL`: o `COALESCE` avalia o argumento para saber se o resultado é nulo e, não sendo, avalia ele de novo para retornar https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/coalesce-vs-isnull ; esse artigo é de 2013 se referindo ao MSSQL 2012, não sei se aplica às versões mais recentes.