# PDO passagem de parâmetro bindValue

Tags: php, pdo, parâmetros

Tenho o seguinte parâmetro em minha consulta de **UPDATE**.

```
$consulta->bindValue(':foto', $foto, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

O que gostaria de fazer é o seguinte: Se a variável  `$foto` vier em branco, como poderia passar o mesmo valor que tenho no banco de dados?

Pergunto isso porque como a variável está vindo em branco ela está fazendo o update no campo sem nenhum valor.

Comment: Verifique se `$foto` está vazio, se estiver não passe, faça assim: `if (!empty($foto)) { $consulta->bindValue(':foto', $foto, PDO::PARAM_STR); } else { // $foto está vazio }`

Comment: se não usar o parâmetro da erro pq ele está na clausula do update

Comment: poderia fazer um select, mas acredito que tenha um outra forma de passar o mesmo valor do campo sem precisar recuperar antes.

Comment: Eu faço assim: quando carregar os dados para alteração, crie um campo `hidden` com o nome `oldfoto` quando você receber as informações para alteração faça um simples `if`. se foto não tiver nada passe novamente a oldfoto. So um ponto, cole o seu html na tela!

Comment: Virgilio Novic, já pensei nisso tbm, mas não gosto de usar muito o campo hiden pois pode abrir brecha de segurança na aplicação, caso o usuário dê um F12 é só ele preencher o campo.

Comment: Esse parâmetro não pode ser opcional? Já tentou usar [`COALESCE`](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55733/6454) para indicar um valor alternativo? não sei se é o seu caso, mas [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23877641/1608936) tem um exemplo que pode ser adaptável.

Comment: stderr, PERFEITO! Tinha esquecido do Coalesce, fiz da seguinte maneira e deu certo!     foto=COALESCE(:foto, foto)

Comment: @William Se possível poste uma resposta e marque-a como resolvida!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabei usando a função do mysql que nosso amigo @stderr postou nos comentários.

```
foto=COALESCE(:foto, foto)
```

Se o parâmetro vier em branco o COALESCE atribui um valor padrão para o campo, que no meu caso é o mesmo valor que já está gravado.