# sql retornar zero

Tags: mysql

o mysql me retorna o seguinte

```
codMunicipio count(codMunicipio)
271              7
273              248
274              18332
275              25
276              4
```

como não o 272 não retornou nenhum, ele não é exibido. Mas eu preciso que retorno o 272 com count 0. Como poderia fazer isso? meu sql está abaixo

```
SELECT artesao.codMunicipio,count(codMunicipio)
FROM `artesao` 
where artesao.codMunicipio > 270 
group by codMunicipio
```

Comment: teria como postar uma foto da tabela? contendo o valor 272?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem que fazer um `RIGHT JOIN`.
Você deve ter uma tabela de municípios. É só fazer a ligação.

```
SELECT
    MUNICIPIO.ID,
    COALESCE (QTD(CODMUNICIPIO), 0) AS QTD
FROM
    ARTESAO
RIGHT JOIN MUNICIPIOS ON MUNICIPIOS.ID = ARTESAO.CODMUNICIPIO
WHERE
    MUNICIPIO.ID > 270
GROUP BY
    MUNICIPIO.ID
```

Comment: continua nao exibindo o 272, eu tenho a tabela municipio, eu tenho o municipio de codigo 272, mas não há nenhum artesao cadastrado com este municipio, usei este codigo e o 272 nao é exibido SELECT
    codMunicipio,
    COALESCE (count(codMunicipio), 0) AS QTD
FROM
    artesao
RIGHT JOIN municipio ON municipio.codigo = artesao.codMunicipio
WHERE
    codMunicipio > 270
GROUP BY
    codMunicipio

Comment: Boa solução, por que COALESCE e não IFNULL? Pelo que parece ele não precisa de "n" argumentos.

Comment: Eu coloquei a coluna errada, tem que ser a coluna ID do Município da tabela de municípios. Editei meu código. Veja agora...

Comment: continua nao exibindo o 272 e o 276 que nao retornam nenhum registro, deixa eu tentar postar uma imagem aqui nao sei se funciona <img src="https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-z0j9kc1KR9o/V-wEw9F5iOI/AAAAAAAAHao/yR8CJnK6J_0FyTku4bLouW8vrUlCdGTFQCLcB/s1600/Capturar.JPG" /><img src="https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-yGg2Y5SXdpE/V-wDj34Ba1I/AAAAAAAAHag/3KuvqHWvpCAsp--qiYXrEClCPfbnA86zgCLcB/s1600/Capturar.JPG" /><img src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-CioawU0B3PE/V-wDcWHdSbI/AAAAAAAAHac/DtKqcBgQcUwsL-CdzGKvQaVABNSV1f37QCLcB/s1600/Capturar.JPG" />

Comment: se puderem clicar nos 3 links, sao tres imagens

Comment: Alterei o código. Veja agora

Answer (score 0):

Se na sua tabela o `codMunicipio` 272 tiver com o `codMunicipio` igual a `NULL`, você pode usar o `IFNULL`.
Ele substitui o valores `NULL` pelo que você quer, no caso 0. A sintaxe é:

```
{fn IFNULL( expressão, substituição )}
```

Exemplo do [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp):

```
SELECT ProductName, UnitPrice*(UnitsInStock+IFNULL(UnitsOnOrder,0))
FROM Products
```

Comment: usei o codigo abaixo e continua nao exibindo o 272, que no caso não tem nenhum registro   SELECT artesao.codMunicipio,IFNULL(count(codMunicipio),0) 
FROM `artesao` 
where artesao.codMunicipio > 270 
group by codMunicipio

Comment: @Adriano, tenta assim: SELECT artesao.codMunicipio, count({ fn IFNULL(codMunicipio, 0) }) AS cod

Comment: eu fiz um count. para o 272 não tem nenhum registro. Mas o 272 existe na tabela codmunicipio. Fiz mais um teste, o 276 estava retornando 6 registro, alterei o codMunicipio destes 6 . agora o 276 tb não é exibido. Preciso que ele exiba com ZERO

Comment: tb nao funcionou com o fb

Comment: @Adriano, posta as tabelas Municipo e Artesao, assim vai dar pra saber o que você quer

Comment: @Taisbevalle a diferença é irrelevante... http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55733/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-isnull-e-coalesce-numa-pesquisa