# Qual a diferença entre COALESCE e NVL

Tags: sql, oracle, pl-sql

No Oracle quando temos uma tabela que possui dois campus A e B, e na seleção (`select`) queremos mostrar B quando o A for nulo temos dois comandos que nos apresentam a solução:

**Coalesce**

```
Select COALESCE(A,B) Teste
 from TabelaTeste
```

**NVL**

```
Select NVL(A,B) Teste
     from TabelaTeste
```

Qual a diferença entre estes comandos? Algum é mais performático? Quais critérios devo utilizar para escolher?

Comment: Relacionado (sobre MS-SQL/T-SQL): https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55733

Answer (score 24, accepted):

A função [**`NVL`**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) é específica do Oracle e só aceita duas expressões como entrada.

Se a primeira expressão for nula, a função retornará a segunda expressão. Caso contrário, será retornada a primeira expressão.

As expressões de entrada também podem ser de tipos diferentes, caso isso aconteça, será feita uma tentativa de *cast* implícito, se o *cast* não for possível será retornado um erro.

Além disso, esta função sempre **avalia** as duas expressões de entrada, fazendo com que ela seja levemente menos performática que a `COALESCE`.

Ilustração da função **`NVL`**:

[image: Função NVL].

<sup>[Imagem da documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm)</sup>

O [**`COALESCE`**](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) faz parte do padrão [ANSI-92](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92), portanto é uma função que existe em todos os bancos de dados que seguem este padrão ou superiores.

Ele retorna sempre o primeiro valor não nulo na lista de expressões. É preciso especificar, no mínimo, duas expressões, mas pode-se especificar mais.

Ilustração da função **`COALESCE`**:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

<sup>[Imagem da documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/img/coalesce.gif)</sup>

Answer (score 11):

As diferenças são:

1. COALESCE segue o padrão ANSI enquanto o NVL é específico do Oracle;
2. NVL aceita apenas 2 agurmentos enquanto que COALESCE pode receber múltiplos argumentos;
3. NVL executa ambos argumentos e COALESCE para na primeira ocorrência de um valor não-nulo;
4. NVL faz uma conversão implícita do tipo de dado baseado no primeiro parâmetro informado, COALESCE espera que todos os parâmetros sejam do mesmo tipo;

Exemplo:

`select nvl('abc',10) from dual;` Irá funcionar com a conversão implícita do número 10 para string.

`select coalesce('abc',10) from dual;` Irá gerar o seguinte erro: "Inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got NUMBER".

5. COALESCE tem problemas em queries que usam clausulas UNION (Exemplo abaixo);

Exemplo:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a, sysdate) 
from (select null as a from dual 
      union 
      select null as a from dual
      );
```

Irá dar o seguinte erro: "ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got DATE".

```
SELECT NVL(a, sysdate) 
from (select null as a from dual 
      union 
      select null as a from dual
      ) ;
```

Executará com sucesso.

Fonte: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34830327)