# CONCAT não está funcionando quando a coluna é NULL

Tags: mysql

Preciso de uma ajuda com o seguinte código:

```
UPDATE propostas SET obs = CONCAT(obs, 'aaa'), cd_status = 0 WHERE tsk_id = 1
```

Se a coluna `obs` estiver nula, não carrega a nova observação.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que nulos não podem ser concatenados com strings, então é preciso um tratamento especial nestes casos.

Uma função que é adequada para estes casos é a `COALESCE`, que permite um valor de fallback no lugar de nulos (ou `IFNULL` nos DBs que suportam, que costuma ser um `COALESCE` de dois valores - não confundir com ISNULL):

```
UPDATE propostas SET obs = CONCAT(COALESCE(obs, ''), 'aaa'), cd_status = 0 WHERE tsk_id = 1
```

O `COALESCE` recebe uma lista de valores, e retorna o primeiro não-nulo dela. Neste caso ele vai retornar `obs` se não for nulo, e a string `""` se `obs` for nulo.

Ainda:

```
UPDATE propostas SET obs = CONCAT( IFNULL(obs,''), 'aaa'), cd_status = 0 WHERE tsk_id = 1
```

Poderia fazer isto no lugar do `COALESCE`, mas fica menos elegante:

```
IF( obs IS NOT NULL, obs, '' )
```

O `IF` testa o primeiro parâmetro para verdadeiro ou falso. Se verdadeiro, retorna o segundo parâmetro, se falso, retorna o terceiro.

Em linguagens onde não há `IF` (nem `IIF`, como no T-SQL antes de 2012) tem o `CASE IF`, mas já foge um pouco da pergunta.

Entenda melhor em:

> [Qual a diferença entre ISNULL e COALESCE numa pesquisa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55733/70)